# What would the size of this nut be?

Tags: bolts

I have this nut that is attached to my bed. However, I don't have access to the bed and hence need to guess the size of this nut so that I can buy the tools for it. Anyone know roughly how big this nut is and what size spanner I would need?

I'm planning on buying this wrench set and would like to know if one of them would fit this nut.[image]
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07L2THNY7/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A3TX3Z5Z5OFI4X&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L2THNY7)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Without anything to give us a sense of scale, it's going to be really, really difficult to guesstimate the size of the nut. If you don't have an SAE (fractional inch size) and a metric open-end wrench set, but you're planning on doing more small projects around the house, this is a _perfect_ time to get one of each.  Get a set of each that contains, at the big end, at least at 1/2" and a 15mm, then give 'em a try until you find something that fits. If you don't want to invest a lot of money at this point, an inexpensive set like you've linked is good (it's max size is only 7/16", though).

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day, we called these wrenches "ignition wrenches" due to their size and their usual usage. So, I would say no to any of them fitting that bolt head and recommend a larger size wrench set. Depending upon who made the bed that bolt head could be a standard USA or metric. My best guess would be a 1/2" box wrench will fit.

Comment: "back in the day" would be the day the seller posted that on Amazon and labeled it as an "Ignition wrench set"? :)

Comment: @ Freeman, you must be a lot older than me since "back in the day" was a saying we used to denote a long time ago ha ha

Comment: I get "back in the day", I was just commenting on the fact that's what they're called in the Amazon listing... #HumorFail